# Why does this JSP scriptlet fail with a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I can print out `pageModel.foo` using EL:

```
${pageModel.foo}
```

But this scriptlet fails at the line where I check the `length()` of `foo`:

```
java.lang.String foo = (java.lang.String)pageContext.getAttribute("pageModel.foo");
if(foo.length()>10){
    foo = foo.substring(0, 9);
}
```

It throws a `NullPointerException` - which doesn't make sense because `${pageModel.foo}` works!

Comment: ${pageModel.foo} != pageContext.getAttribute("pageModel.foo")

Comment: Psssh... JSTL has `fn:length()` and `fn:substring()` functions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with the code you posted:

1. The EL `${pageModel.foo}` doesn't load an attribute called "`pageModel.foo`" - it loads an attribute called "`pageModel`" and gets it's "`foo`" property.
2. `pageContext.getAttribute()` only loads attributes from the page scope. However, EL can access attributes from many scopes - you should use `pageContext.findAttribute()` instead.

code:

```
String foo = "";
PageModel pageModel = (my.package.PageModel)pageContext.findAttribute("pageModel");
if (pageModel != null) {
  foo = pageModel.getFoo();
  if(foo.length()>10){
    foo = foo.substring(0, 9);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already given by Nate, so I won't repeat it.

However, I usually supplement answers with answers which answers what the questioner *really* needs instead of what the questioner asks. It namely look much like that you're totally unaware of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [core tags](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) and [functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html). You should really prefer it over fiddling with ugly *scriptlets*.

```html
<c:set var="foo" value="${pageModel.foo}" />
<c:if test="${fn:length(foo) > 10)}">
    <c:set var="foo" value="${fn.substring(foo, 0, 9)}" />
</c:if>
<p>${foo}</p>
```

or, with the conditional operator `?:`:

```html
<c:set var="foo" value="${(fn:length(pageModel.foo) > 10) ? fn.substring(pageModel.foo, 0, 9) : pageModel.foo}" />
<p>${foo}</p>
```

Much better, isn't it?

Keep in mind: whenever you need a *scriptlet* `<% %>`, then chances are very big that you're looking for a solution in the **wrong** direction. Think twice about finding the solution and look in direction of taglibs, EL functions or just servlets/filters.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is `pageModel`, not `pageModel.foo`.

Not that you should be doing that in a scriptlet anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Map m = (java.util.Map) pageContext.getAttribute("pageModel");
String foo = (String) m.get("foo");
if(foo.length()>10){
    foo = foo.substring(0, 9);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what kind of object pageModel is but its probably a Map.